# Placing numbers around bombs in Minesweeper: why do I get "list index out of range"?

Tags: python, matrix, minesweeper

I have a function that places 'z' amount of bombs randomly scattered across a 10x10 grid. It looks something like this ("b" represents where the bombs are located.) I need to place a number representing how many bombs there are next to the "0" (including diagonals), and I am not sure how to do that.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b 0
b 0 0 b 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 b 0 0 0
0 0 0 b 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 b 0 0 0 0 0 0 b
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 b 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 b 0 b 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

from random import*
mat1 = []
mat2 = []

def makemat(x):
    for y in range(x):
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for z in range(x):
            list1.append(0)
            list2.append("-")
        mat1.append(list1)
        mat2.append(list2)
makemat(5)



def printmat(mat):
    for a in range(len(mat)):
        for b in range(len(mat)):
            print(str(mat[a][b]) + "\t",end="")
        print("\t")



def addmines(z):
    count = 0
    while (count < z):
        x = randrange(0,len(mat1))       
        y = randrange(0,len(mat1))      
        if mat1[y][x] == "b":
            count -= 1
        else:
            mat1[y][x] = "b"
        count += 1
    printmat(mat1)
addmines(10)
```

This is the function I tried for placing the numbers:

```
def addscores():
    for x in range(len(mat1)):
        for y in range(len(mat1)):
            if mat1[y][x] != "b":
                if mat1[y+1][x] == "b":
                    mat1[y][x] = 1 
                if mat1[y-1][x] == "b":
                    mat1[y][x] = 1                  #...ETC
            else:
                mat1[y][x] == "b"
addscores()
```

I keep getting the error *list index out of range*. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Might I suggest using a numpy array to store your board?  Then to check nearest neighbours, you can use a simple array slice and not have to worry about the boundary conditions.

Comment: In Python, it doesn't make sense to loop over indices of a list. Loop over the list itself.

Comment: As an extra note, that applies [even if you need neighbouring items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12842104/722121) - something like that could be expanded to give more items, although as wim said, numpy might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if mat1[y+1][x] == "b":
```

to

```
if safeEquals(mat1, y+1, x, "b"):
```

and define safeEquals as

```
def safeEquals(mat, y, x, value):
    try:
        return mat1[y][x] == "b"
    except IndexError as e:
        return False
```

This essentially allows you to provide a default behaviour if you index outside the map position.

PS the code executed after the condition:

```
mat1[y][x] = 1
```

should be

```
mat1[y][x] += 1
```

as presence of an adjacent bomb increments the bomb counter (otherwise how does a 3 ever appear on the map_

Comment: Format your code using the `{}` button in the response editor.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `(x, y) = (9, 9)`, you get the `IndexError` because you do:

```
if mat1[y+1][x] == "b":
```

which tries to access the index `mat1[10]`, which doesn't exists because your list is only 10 elements long.

Also, let's say that `(x, y) = (0, 0)`. Then when you do:

```
if mat1[y-1][x] == "b":
```

You access the index `mat[-1]`, which is equivalent to `mat[9]`. I'm pretty sure this is not what you intend.

There are 2 easy ways to correct this:

1) Include an additional set of `if` statements to ensure that you don't attempt to access list elements outside the bounds of the list:

Change:

```
            if mat1[y+1][x] == "b":
                mat1[y][x] = 1 
            if mat1[y-1][x] == "b":
                mat1[y][x] = 1
```

To:

```
            #parentheses in if statements added for clarity
            if (y < len(mat1) - 1) and (mat1[y+1][x] == "b"):
                mat1[y][x] = 1 
            if (y > 0) and (mat1[y-1][x] == "b"):
                mat1[y][x] = 1
```

2) This is the method I prefer. Add a layer of "padding" around the array. When you first create your array, do:

```
WIDTH = 10
HEIGHT = 10

myMap = [[0 for i in range(WIDTH + 2)] for j in range(HEIGHT + 2)]
```

Then, when you access elements in your array, just make sure that you are indexing from 1, not 0:

```
#do this
firstElement = myMap[1][1]

#not this
firstElement = mayMap[0][0]

#do this
for i in range(1, len(myMap) - 1): pass

#not this
for i in range(len(myMap)): pass
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to avoid the index errors is to use `defaultdict` to hold `mat1` and `mat2`. As a bonus the code is shorter :)

```
from random import randrange
from collections import defaultdict
mat1 = defaultdict(int)
mat2 = defaultdict(lambda:"-")
size = 5

def printmat(mat):
    for a in range(size):
        print("\t".join(str(mat[a, b]) for b in range(size)))


def addmines(count):
    while (count):
        x = randrange(0,size)       
        y = randrange(0,size)      
        if mat1[y, x] != "b":
            mat1[y, x] = "b"
            count -= 1
    printmat(mat1)
addmines(10)

def addscores():
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if mat1[y, x] != "b":
                if mat1[y+1, x] == "b":
                    mat1[y, x] = 1                  # should be +=
                if mat1[y-1, x] == "b":
                    mat1[y, x] = 1                  #...ETC
            else:
                mat1[y, x] == "b"
addscores()
```

Answer (score -1):

if y is in range(len(mat1)) then y+1 is not...

Comment: Is this supposed to be executable python?